# How to filter files in gulp.pipe() based on filename that contains specific text?

Tags: javascript, filter, gulp, pipe

I wanted to filter .pug files in gulp.pipe() in the following way:

If the file name contains specific text for example "section" it is ignored if not it is piped further and saved. I'm using gulp-ignore plugin.
The ignore keywords are stored in the array:

```
var ignoreArr = [
    "index",
    "base",
    "elem",
    "temp",
    "footer",
    "header",
    "layout",
    "section"
];
```

I used solution from found elsewhere to get filename in pipe

```
var es, log, logFile;

es = require('event-stream');

log = require('gulp-util').log;

logFile = function(es) {
  return es.map(function(file, cb) {
    log(file.path);
    return cb();
  });
};
```

I have a problem in integrating it with gulp task

```
gulp.task("gen", function() {
 return gulp.src('./src/*.pug')
  .pipe(gulpIgnore.exclude(new RegExp(ignoreArr.join("|")).test(logFile(es)) == false))
        .pipe(
            pug({
                locals:  {
                    message: 'test',
                }
            })
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another, simpler solution:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const filter = require('gulp-filter');
const path = require('path');

var ignoreArr = [
  "index",
  "base",
  "elem",
  "temp",
  "footer",
  "header",
  "layout",
  "section"
];


gulp.task('default', function () {

  // return true if want the file in the stream
  const myFilter = filter(function (file) {

    let baseName = path.basename(file.path, '.pug');

    // is the test function (!String.includes) satisfied for every element of the ignoreArr
    return ignoreArr.every(ignoreEntry => !baseName.includes(ignoreEntry));
  });

  return gulp.src(['./src/*.pug'])

    .pipe(myFilter)
    // .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: what if we get an error when we run this that states  - `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module`? Are we no longer allowed to use require on gulp-filter?

Comment: @klewis See https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-filter/issues/97 and the link therein: https://gist.github.com/noraj/007a943dc781dc8dd3198a29205bae04 and its comments.  Caveat: I haven't tried this yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by myself using gulp-foreach plugin.

```
gulp.task("gen", function() {
gulp.src('./src/*.pug')
    .pipe(foreach(function(stream, file) {
            var name = path.basename(file.path, '.pug'); 
            var cond = (new RegExp(ignoreArr.join("|")).test(name) == true)
            console.log(cond)
            return stream
                .pipe(
                    pug({
                        locals: {
                          message: 'test',
                        }
                    })
                )
                .pipe(gulpIgnore.exclude(cond))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));

            console.log(stream)
        })
    );
```

})